# Hexdump: Convert between bytes and two-byte decimal

Tags: byte, hexdump, radix

When I use `hexdump` on a file with no options, I get rows of hexadecimal bytes:

```
cf fa ed fe 07 00 00 01 03 00 00 80 02 00 00 00
```

When I used `hexdump -d` on the same file, that same data is shown in something called two-byte decimal groupings:

```
64207   65261   00007   00256   00003   32768   00002   00000
```

So what I'm trying to figure out here is how to convert between these two encodings. `cf` and `fa` in decimal are `207` and `250` respectively. How do those numbers get combined to make `64207`?

Bonus question: What is the advantage of using these groupings? The octal display uses 16 groupings of three digits, why not use the same thing with the decimal display?

Comment: `0xfa * 256 + 0xcf == 0xfacf == 64207`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @georg.

> `0xfa * 256 + 0xcf == 0xfacf == 64207`

The conversion exactly works like this.

So, if you see `man hexdump`:

> ```
> -d, --two-bytes-decimal
>               Two-byte decimal display.  Display the input offset in hexadecimal, followed by eight
>               space-separated,  five-column, zero-filled, two-byte units of input data, in unsigned
>               decimal, per line.
> ```

So, for example:

```
00000f0   64207   65261   00007   00256   00003   32768   00002   00000
```

Here, `00000f0` is a hexadecimal offset.

Followed by two-byte units of input data, for eg.: `64207` in decimal (first 16 bits - i.e. two bytes of the file).

The conversion (in your case):

`cf fa` ----> two-byte unit (the [byte ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) depends on your architecture).

`fa * 256 + cf = facf` ----> appropriately ----> `0xfacf` (re-ording)

And dec of `oxfacf` is `64207`.

Bonus question: It is a convention to display octal numbers using three digits (unlike hex and decimal), so it uses a triplet for each byte.

Comment: Thanks, @Rutaraj! My bonus question might have been unclear, though; what I meant to ask about is the benefit of using two-byte units for the decimal display. I don't understand why you wouldn't just use single-byte units the way it's done with all the other radixes.